# Issue with DataContractSurrogate in the Debugger

Tags: silverlight, wcf, debugging, wcf-ria-services

Having big issues running my project locally. When I run it and get to this piece of code.

```
_institutionRepository.All();
```

when i step over this with debugger I get this inside the _`institutionRepository` object

Results View = The type 'Project1.Entities.DataAccess.Institution' exists in both 'Project1.Entities.DataAccess.dll' and 'DataContractSurrogates_40d75f07-afb1-4694-833a-ea508af1e0ac'

But when the rest of my team runs this locally they do not get this issue. I have been researching this for too long and need to get this resolved quickly. Any ideas would be appreciated.

i am running on VS2010 with silverlight and RiaSerivces

Comment: After walking through this with another developer on our team. We have found that it is not just happening on my local machine. That it is in fact happening on other boxes. Which is good, although still no solution to the issues.. Greg, thanks for the feedback and Im making amends to my other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure of this message. but we found the issue and it had nothing to do with the message received. One of our fields in the DB is supposed to be one of two types and we had the wrong one entered. So i am receiving data back. But this error/message is there with every entity in our solution. I would like to know more about it.

Comment: to follow up, it seems that each entity had this issue and the error was not causing any issues.